# how to disable drop text inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

How to prevent users from dragging and dropping text inside a textarea? is there an attribute which control this or need some js code?

**Want to disable drop but not to make it readonly**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do is an usability fault, but never mind...

```
<textarea ondrop="return false;">
```

I assume you don't want to disable normal typing into it.

Comment: it _does_ work on Firefox 17 and Chrome 23. Thanks very much for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
<textarea ondragstart="return false" ondrop="return false">
```

While am trying with this code,its working fine in all browsers....

Answer (score -4):

Yes the attributes name is `disabled`:

```
<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Comment: I want to let the user write in the textarea

Comment: Then I don't even understood your requirement. "dropping text" is just another way of putting text into a `textarea`, like writing or pasting?! It seems very strange to me, allowing the one method, but forbidding another—as @duri said: it's an usability fault…

Comment: @feeela, thought about HTML5 applications where the user could drop a element into the element which isn't text? A spotify track for example? It's NOT an usability fault.

Comment: @schlingel Yes it is, because in HTML5 apps you won't use a textarea as drop zone. Textarea is a form element with a specific function. It's not in any suiteg for any other data than text and one can't insert an image or other media into a textarea.

Comment: @feeela Ever tried to build an Spotify app? It's easily possible to drop a track, a playlist or any other object into it. The default behavior is to place the URI of the entity in the textarea.

Comment: @schlingel o why do want to paste an URL into an input but not allow to change it? That is the usability fault I was talking about…

Comment: @feeela because nobody needs the URL and the user has no way to access the URL directly. The only way to see it is to drop the item in the TextArea. If he likes to enter a URL himself it's OK to us but we don't want to destroy the message when the user accidentally drops an entity on the message box. That's not an usability fault.