# How to disable Drag&drop in Textarea

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am creating a textarea for collecting user info from customers, some of them try to drag an image file into that textarea and causes image displayed in the same window of browser and lost the current running site address. So what will I do? How to prevent this drag&drop property in that form?

Comment: possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273883/how-to-disable-drop-text-inside-a-textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put ondragstart="return false" and ondrop="return false" properties on the textarea element, it would working fine in all browsers..

```
<textarea ondragstart="return false" ondrop="return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this on your text area, it will completely disable the drag drop functionality..

```
<textarea ondragstart="return false" ondrop="return false">
```

Try it ... works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea ondrop="return false;">
```

Have a look on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273883/how-to-disable-drop-text-inside-a-textarea)

Comment: possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273883/how-to-disable-drop-text-inside-a-textarea

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply...
While i trying <textarea ondragstart="return false" ondrop="return false"> its working fine in browsers...